# Phoenix doesn't render associations

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a simple Todo/Author/Comment

```
Todo has_many comments
Comment belongs_to Todo
Todo belongs_to Author
Author has_many todos
Author has_many comments
Comment belongs_to Author
```

If I render the todo_view.ex like this:

```
  def render("todo.json", %{todo: todo}) do
    %{id: todo.id,
      title: todo.title,
      description: todo.description,
      date: todo.date,
      author: author_json(todo.author)}
  end
  defp author_json(author) do
    %{name: author.name}
  end
```

Everything works fine when I access `/api/todos` and `/api/comments`
But if I want to add the list of comments for the todos:

```
  def render("todo.json", %{todo: todo}) do
    %{id: todo.id,
      title: todo.title,
      description: todo.description,
      date: todo.date,
      author: author_json(todo.author),
      comments: render_many(todo.comments, CommentView, "comment.json")}
  end
```

I get a KeyError in comment_view.ex

> key :name not found in: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded

```
  def render("comment.json", %{comment: comment}) do
    %{id: comment.id,
      content: comment.content,
      author: author_json(comment.author)}
  end
  defp author_json(author) do
    %{name: author.name}
  end
```

Somehow Elixir doesn't see the Comment / Author association when querying todos, but it does see it when querying comments.

I did the preloading for comment:

```
comments = Repo.all(Comment) |> Repo.preload(:author)
```

Any idea what's happening here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you preload `author` when you fetched the `todos` from the database?
Something like this:

```
todos = Todo |> Repo.all() |> Repo.preload([comments: [:author]])
```

This loads for all `ToDos` the `Comments` with their `Author` associations.

Comment: I had preload(:author) and preload(:comments) but replacing preload(:comments) by your version works. thanks!